# Android, my app looks good on vertical screens, but size is all distorted on tablets (wide screen)

Tags: android

When my android app gets drawn on a tablet or a emulator that has a wide screen (wasvga,wxcage800 and my tablet) it draws the graphic images from the drawblw-ldpi folder (low res) instead of the drawl-hdpi folder. I'm curtly using a bitmap button.  They are all very small (since the smallest image is being drawn) on the tables, but the correct image gets drawn on all the vertical screens.

Why is this????
Is there a way to fix it????

Answer (score 0):

The default folder is the mdpi folder. If another folder doesn't exist, or doesn't have your image, android gets it from drawable-mdpi. Put your images there, and let us know if it works.

Comment: Hi, i rename the res folders to drawable-low, drawable-low and drawl-normal. I found some document ion that says this will set the size sep and x and y size not dot pitch but thank you for your suggestion